# Issue with material ui DataGrid pageSize and scrolling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, scroll

I'm using material ui DataGrid component to show my incident file records received from vehicle blackbox which will contain 135 records. Now by default I'm setting pagesize as 100 and I set DataGrid height to '75vh'. Irrespective of pagesize selected let it be 15,20,100 only 11 rows are displaying on my screen by leaving empty space till footer and remaining all rows from 12 are scrolling down. For pagesizes like 5,10 it's working fine.Please help me to sort it out. I want to display as maximum as possible rows on my screen. Here is my attached 'incidentFile' code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Typography, Paper, Button, Breadcrumbs, Link, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { madasIncidentService, madasIncidentRecordService, madasDeviceConfigService, madasDeviceService } from "../../services";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { downloadAsCSV } from "../../utils";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const IncidentFile = () => {
  const { id, incidentId } = useParams();
  const [incidentFile, setIncidentFile] = useState(null);
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [deviceConfig, setDeviceConfig] = useState(null);
  const [device, setDevice] = useState(null);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  const user = useSelector(store => store.auth.user);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const theme = useTheme();

  const INCIDENT_BREAK_POINT = tableData.length - 15; // 120th record in 135
  const headerNamesDict = columns.reduce((acc, col) => {
    acc[col.field] = col.headerName;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const formattedCSVData = tableData.map(obj => {
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      newObj[headerNamesDict[key] || key] = obj[key];
    });
    return newObj;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!deviceConfig?.reportfields) return;
    const reportfields = deviceConfig.reportfields.reduce((acc, field) => {
      acc[field] = true;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    const cols = [
      { field: "id", headerName: "R.No", width: 50, show: true },
      { field: "systemTime", headerName: "System Time", width: 150, show: true },
      { field: "channel1", headerName: deviceConfig.channel1 || "Channel 1", width: 100, show: reportfields.channel1 },
      { field: "channel2", headerName: deviceConfig.channel2 || "Channel 2", width: 100, show: reportfields.channel2 },
      { field: "channel3", headerName: deviceConfig.channel3 || "Channel 3", width: 100, show: reportfields.channel3 },
      { field: "channel4", headerName: deviceConfig.channel4 || "Channel 4", width: 100, show: reportfields.channel4 },
      { field: "latitude", headerName: "Latitude", width: 110, show: reportfields.latitude },
      { field: "longitude", headerName: "Longitude", width: 110, show: reportfields.longitude },
      { field: "gpsTime", headerName: "GPS Time", width: 150, show: reportfields.gpsTime },
      { field: "altitude", headerName: "Altitude", width: 110, show: reportfields.altitude },
      { field: "speed", headerName: "Speed", width: 110, show: reportfields.speed },
      { field: "fixStatus", headerName: "Fix Status", width: 100, show: reportfields.fixStatus },
      { field: "gpsStatus", headerName: "GPS Status", width: 100, show: reportfields.gpsStatus },
      { field: "x", headerName: "X-Accel", width: 110, show: reportfields.x },
      { field: "y", headerName: "Y-Accel", width: 110, show: reportfields.y },
      { field: "z", headerName: "Z-Accel", width: 110, show: reportfields.z },
      { field: "enginerpm", headerName: "Engine RPM", width: 100, show: reportfields.enginerpm },
      { field: "brakePressure", headerName: "Brake Pressure", width: 120, show: reportfields.brakePressure },
      { field: "brakePedalPosition", headerName: "Brake Pedal Position", width: 150, show: reportfields.brakePedalPosition },
      { field: "steeringangle", headerName: "Steering Angle", width: 120, show: reportfields.steeringangle },
      { field: "throttlePosition", headerName: "Throttle Position", width: 120, show: reportfields.throttlePosition },
      { field: "pgn1", headerName: "PGN1", width: 350, show: reportfields.pgn1 },
      { field: "pgn2", headerName: "PGN2", width: 350, show: reportfields.pgn2 },
      { field: "pgn3", headerName: "PGN3", width: 350, show: reportfields.pgn3 },
      { field: "pgn4", headerName: "PGN4", width: 350, show: reportfields.pgn4 },
      { field: "pgn5", headerName: "PGN5", width: 350, show: reportfields.pgn5 },
      { field: "ignition", headerName: "Ignition", width: 150, show: reportfields.ignition },
      { field: "input1", headerName: deviceConfig.input1 || "Input 1", width: 50, show: reportfields.input1 },
      { field: "input2", headerName: deviceConfig.input2 || "Input 2", width: 50, show: reportfields.input2 },
      { field: "input3", headerName: deviceConfig.input3 || "Input 3", width: 50, show: reportfields.input3 },
    ];
    setColumns(cols.filter(col => col.show));
  }, [deviceConfig]);

  useEffect(() => {
    madasIncidentService.retreive(incidentId).then(res => {
      setIncidentFile(res.data);
      madasIncidentRecordService.list({ incident_id: incidentId }).then(res => {
        const data = res?.data?.map((item, index) => {
          const data = item.recordValues;
          return {
            id: item.recordNumber,
            systemTime: data.systemtime,
            latitude: data.gps.Latitude,
            longitude: data.gps.Longitude,
            gpsTime: data.gps.Time,
            altitude: data.gps.Altitude,
            speed: data.gps.Speed,
            fixStatus: data.gps.FixStatus,
            gpsStatus: data.gps.GPSStatus,
            x: data.accel.x,
            y: data.accel.y,
            z: data.accel.z,
            enginerpm: data.can.enginerpm,
            brakePressure: data.can.brakePressure,
            brakePedalPosition: data.can.brakePedalPosition,
            steeringangle: data.can.steeringangle,
            throttlePosition: data.can.throttlePosition,
            pgn1: data.can.pgn1,
            pgn2: data.can.pgn2,
            pgn3: data.can.pgn3,
            pgn4: data.can.pgn4,
            pgn5: data.can.pgn5,
            channel1: data.adc.channel1,
            channel2: data.adc.channel2,
            channel3: data.adc.channel3,
            channel4: data.adc.channel4,
            ignition: data.inputs.ignition,
            input1: data.inputs.input1,
            input2: data.inputs.input2,
            input3: data.inputs.input3,
          };
        });
        data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
        setTableData(data.map((data, index) => ({ ...data, index: index + 1 })));
      });

      madasDeviceConfigService.list({ device_id: res.data.device_id }).then(res => {
        setDeviceConfig(res.data[0]);
      });
    });

    madasDeviceService.retreive(id).then(res => {
      setDevice(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", margin: "20px 0px" }}>
        {/* <>{incidentFile?.filename}</> */}
        <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <Link underline="hover" sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }} color="inherit" onClick={() => navigate("/madas")}>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">All Devices</Typography>
          </Link>
          {user.type === "SUPER_ADMIN" && (
            <Link underline="hover" sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }} color="inherit" onClick={() => navigate(`/madas/device/${id}`)}>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1">{device?.vehiclecallsign}</Typography>
            </Link>
          )}
          <Link underline="hover" sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }} color="inherit" onClick={() => navigate(`/madas/incidents/${id}`)}>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">Incidents</Typography>
          </Link>
          <Link underline="hover" sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }} color="inherit" onClick={() => navigate(`/madas/incident-file/${id}/${incidentId}`)}>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">{incidentFile?.filename}</Typography>
          </Link>
        </Breadcrumbs>
        <Button
          sx={{ height: "30px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => downloadAsCSV(formattedCSVData, incidentFile?.filename?.split(".json")[0])}
        >
          <Typography>Export CSV</Typography>
        </Button>
      </div>
      <DataGrid
        sx={{
          "&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within": {
            outline: "none !important",
          },
          "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
            color: "white",
          },
          [`& .MuiDataGrid-row[data-rowindex='${INCIDENT_BREAK_POINT - 1}']`]: {
            backgroundColor: "secondary.light",
          },
          border: "1px solid black",
          borderRadius: 2,
          height: "75vh",
          ml: 1,
        }}
        initialState={{
          pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 100 } },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[10, 15, 20, 50, 100]}
        pagination
        rows={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default IncidentFile;
```

I tried giving rowHeight, autopageSize, autoheight. None of the approach worked for me. My requirement is to keep DataGrid height fixed to '75vh' and to accomodate as maximum as possible rows based on selected pagesize.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).